# Where can I ask questions about patents?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

What would be the best Stack Exchange website to ask questions about patents? For example, the best way to patent a given idea in the artistic / creation field.

Comment: Note, there are recommendations to not ask "what is the best way", generally, avoid that line of questioning on Stack Exchange.  If you simply ask "how do I go about doing this" and show what you've tried, that will generally be well-received assuming your question is on-topic for the site.

Answer (score 12):

Probably in your patent lawyer's office. There is patents.stackexchange.com, but that isn't a patent law advice site.

Answer (score 8):

There's the [Patents](https://patents.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchange site.

However, it states it's:

> for people interested in improving and participating in the patent system.

So I don't think that your question about the best way to patent something would necessarily be on topic.

As a general rule if you are asking for "the best X" then your question is highly likely to get closed as not constructive (at best) on *any* site in the network.

Answer (score 1):

That would be on **[Patents](https://patents.stackexchange.com/)**.

Comment: Be sure to check the [about page](http://patents.stackexchange.com/about) on whether the question you intend to ask is within the scope of the site (it sounds like it probably is, if it falls into the "Patent law or the patent approval process" category).

Comment: *[Ask Patents](https://patents.stackexchange.com/tour)*